# Error when trying to set a TAG to a Fragment in Android

Tags: android, android-fragments, tags, fragmentmanager

I have an activity named: `ShoppingListActivity` in which i have added 3 fragments. For this example i will use only one fragment. In `onCreate` method i have declared a `ViewPager` that looks like this:

```
ViewPager viewPager = (ViewPager) findViewById(R.id.view_pager);
```

and a `setupViewPager(viewPager);` method that looks like this:

```
private void setupViewPager(ViewPager viewPager) {
    ViewPagerAdapter adapter = new ViewPagerAdapter(getSupportFragmentManager());

    Fragment shoppingListFragment = new ShoppingListFragment();
    getSupportFragmentManager().beginTransaction().add(shoppingListFragment, "ShoppingListFragmentTag").commit();
    adapter.addFragment(shoppingListFragment, "SHOPPING LIST");

    viewPager.setAdapter(adapter);
}
```

My `ViewPagerAdapter` class lookslike this:

```
private class ViewPagerAdapter extends FragmentPagerAdapter {
    private final List<Fragment> fragmentList = new ArrayList<>();
    private final List<String> fragmentTitleList = new ArrayList<>();

    ViewPagerAdapter(FragmentManager manager) {
        super(manager);
    }

    @Override
    public Fragment getItem(int position) {
        return fragmentList.get(position);
    }

    @Override
    public int getCount() {
        return fragmentList.size();
    }

    void addFragment(Fragment fragment, String title) {
        fragmentList.add(fragment);
        fragmentTitleList.add(title);
    }

    @Override
    public CharSequence getPageTitle(int position) {
        return fragmentTitleList.get(position);
    }
}
```

My problem is when i go from `ShoppingListActivity` to another activity and than come back, my fragments are not refreshed. This is my code from `onResume` method in which i try to find the fragment to detach and attach the fragment like this:

```
FragmentManager fragmentManager = getSupportFragmentManager();
ShoppingListFragment shoppingListFragment = (ShoppingListFragment) fragmentManager.findFragmentByTag("ShoppingListFragmentTag");
fragmentManager.beginTransaction().detach(shoppingListFragment).attach(shoppingListFragment).commit();
```

The problem is that i get this error: `java.lang.IllegalStateException: Can't change tag of fragment ShoppingListFragment{528673f4 #0 ShoppingListFragmentTag}: was ShoppingListFragmentTag now android:switcher:2131558559:0`

How can i set the Tag correctly to the fragment?

Thanks in advance!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

from the code what I understand is, There is a ViewPager implemented in ShoppingListActivity along with tabs.

In viewpager each fragment contains the list of something which come from server right? Now you want to refresh whole viewpager when user back from the ShoppingListInfoActivity right?

Do below changes in you ShoppinglistActivity.

1) Declare `ViewPagerAdapter adapter;` at class level global.

2)change `private class ViewPagerAdapter extends FragmentPagerAdapter`

replace FragmentPagerAdapter to FragmentStatePagerAdapter

3) change in onresume()

```
@Override
protected void onResume() {
    super.onResume();

    if(adapter!=null){
        adapter.notifyDataSetChanged();
    }

}
```

Comment: Thanks you! Right answer.